# PHP Determining and Removing Background Color of Image

Tags: php, image

I've been looking at CustomInk's [design lab](http://www.customink.com/lab?ref=nav_v2) and I am very curious as to how they decide what color is the background color. For example, If I upload the Facebook logo, they decide to remove the blue from the image.

[image]

But if I upload a picture of an apple with a white background, then they remove the white in a similar fashion. (even though the white background is not the dominant color)

Using ImageMagick in PHP, how could I also achieve this task?

Comment: I dunno if this is really an appropriate question or not,  but my best guess is they're assuming the predominant colour in the image is the background.  it'd work for many (most) cases.

Comment: Whoever voted to close, please explain how I could modify my approach on asking this in a way that isn't considered too broad.

Comment: I don't think so, because if I upload the picture of the apple I talked about, the apple was most of the image, but with a white edge, and it still figured out that the white was the color to remove

Comment: I think the question is "to broad" because there can be several ways on how the background color is determed or even a combination of ways. Though I'm not the one that voted the close.

Comment: I did change it just now to hopefully get around this, asking for someone to provide a solution to also achieving this given the same tools I am using

Comment: After playing around with that website, I've determined they're using the outer line pixels to get the background color. The one that's predominant will be assumed as the background color. In case it's a 50/50, it'll probebly follow the color pallete on which to choose (or a random one), or the right one, top one, whatever they're using to choose in a 50/50 case.

Comment: Take a look here: http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.trimimage.php And here: http://phpimagick.com/Imagick/trimImage Not exactly sure if it determines the background if no color given though.

Comment: I've added my own answer, as I've created my own solution

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've found a solution to finding a background color in an image and removing it with PHP and Imagick. I, instead of using the edges, decided to use the corners to figure out which colors to remove, which seemed to be working most of the time. Below are some results.

[image]

Which I was able to get to turn into this

[image]

(the background image is a texture of a white woven material I found on Google). But this seemed to handle gradient backgrounds pretty decently as well.

[image]

This is a picture of a Vette with the original first, then changing all the corners' colors to transparent, and the final is one using fill starting from the corners.

```
$Image = new Imagick('vette.jpg');
$BackgroundColors = array(
    'TopLeft' => array(1, 1),
    'TopRight' => array($Image->getimagewidth(), 1),
    'BottomLeft' => array(1, $Image->getimageheight()),
    'BottomRight' => array($Image->getimagewidth(), $Image->getimageheight())
);

foreach ($BackgroundColors as $Key => $BG) {
    $pixel = $Image->getImagePixelColor($BG[0], $BG[1]);
    $colors = $pixel->getColor();
    $ExcludedColors[] = sprintf("%6X",array_values($colors));
    $Image->floodfillPaintImage('none', 9000, $pixel, $BG[0] - 1, $BG[1] - 1, false);
    //Comment the line above and uncomment the below line to achieve the effects of the second Vette
    //$Image->transparentPaintImage($pixel, 0, 9000, false);
}
$Image->writeImage("vette-no_background.png");
```